# Let $G = \langle A,B,C,D\rangle$. If $\langle X,Y\rangle$ is free of rank $2$ for every $X\neq Y,X,Y\in \{A,B,C,D\}$, is $G$ free of rank $4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G = \langle A, B, C, D\rangle$. If $\langle X, Y\rangle$ is free of rank two for every $X\neq Y, X, Y\in \{A, B, C, D\}$, is $G$ free of rank four?

This question was inspired by a lecture in my algebra class where we discussed something somewhat similar :)

Comment: A more difficult question would be "Is $G$ necessarily free?". The answer to that is also no.

Comment: @DerekHolt $\langle A,B,C,D|(AB)^2=(CD)^2\rangle$ is not free as it contains a subgroup spanned by $AB, CD$ whose abelianisation is $\mathbb Z \times C_2$.

Comment: @tkf Another example is the surface group $\langle a,b,c,d \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1} \rangle$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That is nice - proving geometrically that it is not free.

Answer (score 9):

No. Let $G$ be free of rank $2$ in $x$ and $y$. Let $A=x$, $B=y$, $C=yxy^{-1}$, and $D=y^2xy^{-2}$. Each of $\langle x,y\rangle$, $\langle x,yxy^{-1}\rangle$, $\langle x,y^{2}xy^{-2}\rangle$, $\langle y,yxy^{-1}\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$, $\langle y,y^2xy^{-2}\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$, and $\langle yxy^{-1},y^2xy^{-2}\rangle$ are free of rank $2$, but $\langle x,y,yxy^{-1},y^2xy^{-2}\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ is free of rank $2$, not $4$.

Comment: Is there any condition that we could impose on $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ to make this true?

Comment: @user8253417: Not of the kind you are proposing. You could require even that any three-element subset generate a free group of rank $3$ and you would still not get that the subgroup generated by all four is free of rank $4$. “Any condition” is too broad to answer: I mean, you could require that they generate a free group of rank 4, and that would be a condition that would imply it... but clearly not what you want.

Comment: @user8253417: For an example with $3$-element subsets giving you a free group of rank $3$, take $G$ to be free in $x,y,z$, and let $A=x$, $B=y$, $C=z$, $D=xyz$.

Answer (score 4):

Another example: $$G=\langle A,B,C,D|\,\, AB=CD \rangle$$

Then $G$ is a free rank 3 group on any triple from $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: That is true for every $n$-generated  1-relator group if the relator contains all generators. by Magnus' freedom theorem: every set of $n-1$ generators generates a free subgroup of rank $n-1$.

Comment: The theorem is normally refered to as the [Freiheitssatz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiheitssatz). Also you need the extra condition that the relator is cyclically reduced(as is basically always the case when discussing presentations).

Comment: It is a theorem of Kapovich and Schupp that in a "random" one relator group $\langle a_1, \ldots, a_m\mid R\rangle$, every subgroup generated by at most $m-1$ elements is free. So this gives a strong version of this Freiheitssatz-based result. The reference is I. Kapovich, and P. Schupp, "Genericity, the Arzhantseva-Ol’shanskii method and the isomorphism problem for one-relator groups." Math. Ann. 331.1 (2005): 1-19 ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210307)).